# How can I sort a csv file with mergesort by its date if the date is a string?

Tags: python, csv, date, dictionary, mergesort

I have a list of dictionaries of items. And I am trying to order them with merge sort by date.

```
def merge(left, right):
    result=[]
    p1=0
    p2=0

    while p1<len(left) and p2<len(right):
        if left[p1]<right[p2]:
            result.append(left[p1])
            p1=p1+1
        else:
            result.append(right[p2])
            p2=p2+1

    while p2<len(right):
        result.append(right[p2])
        p2=p2+1

    while p1<len(left):
        result.append(left[p1])
        p1=p1+1

    return result

def merge_sort(lista):

    if len(lista)<1:
        return lista

    mid = len(lista) // 2
    left = lista[:mid]
    right = lista[mid:]
    merge_sort(left)
    merge_sort(right)

    return merge(left, right)
```

The trouble I am having is that I don't know what information I should put in the mergesort(list) because all the dates are strings, and don't know how to convert them into integers. And even if the dates I had was a number of days that have passed since "x day", I don't know how ordering just the dates, can help the entire line.

I understand that it is possible to use datetime or sorted, but is there any way other than using these functions?

This is the data which I transformed from .csv

```
list= {   10:{"Name":"Potato","Date":"2005-12-03"},
          20:{"Name":"Tomato","Date":"2002-03-13"}
          30:{"Name":"Banana","Date":"2003-04-15"}
          40:{"Name":"Orange","Date":"2004-01-22"}
```

Maybe I can sort by year, then by month, and finally by date? But wouldn't that mean that I have to create multiple dictionaries/lists in order to iterate them inside the mergesort function?

Comment: If you use string ordering, dates like `"2005-12-03"` and `"2002-03-13"` are already [lexicographically ordered](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographic_order). A comparison like `"2002-03-13" < "2003-04-15"` returns `True`, for example. I assume you want to sort by date in that manner.

Comment: Right.  If your dates were in the form "03-DEC-2005", then you would need to transform them.  What you have will sort properly as a string.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know. Thank you very much.